# Extracting Data From webpage with python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How can I extract the following html code from its xpath and finally extract the value "790.00” inside the h4 tag?

```
<div class="media-body text-right">

  <h4 style="color:#fff;font-weight:bold"> 790.00</h4>
  <span style="color:white;font-weight:bold">Current Balance (Earn)</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Maybe:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import etree

text = '''
<div class="media-body text-right">

  <h4 style="color:#fff;font-weight:bold"> 790.00</h4>
  <span style="color:white;font-weight:bold">Current Balance (Earn)</span>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "html.parser")
dom = etree.HTML(str(soup))
print(dom.xpath('//div[contains(@class,"media-body text-right")]')[0][0].text)

790.00
```

Other ways (without XPath etc.) are possible.  For example:

```
for divs_class in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "media-body text-right"}):
    for h4s in divs_class.find_all("h4"):
        print(h4s.text)

790.00
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
s = '''<div class="media-body text-right">

  <h4 style="color:#fff;font-weight:bold"> 790.00</h4>
  <span style="color:white;font-weight:bold">Current Balance (Earn)</span>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'lxml')
d = soup.find('div', class_='media-body')
h4 = d.find('h4')
print(h4.text.strip())
```

```
790.00
```